Invalid __global__ write despite index being within bounds
I have a device function that is throwing Invalid __global__ write of size 4 bytes that I have spent several hours debugging to no avail.
The function in question looks like this (with irrelevant bits removed):
__device__ inline int64_t divider() {
    const uint32_t look_up_table[] = { /* 33 const values*/ };

    struct divider_node {
        int64_t diff;
        int32_t left;
        int32_t sign;
    }

    divider_node* div_nodes = new divider_node[33];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
        div_nodes[i].left = (int32_t)look_up_table[i]; // <--- offending line
       
        // rest of loop
    }

    // rest of function

}

I for the life of me can't figure out why this is an invalid write? new should have allocated enough memory for 33 divider nodes and the loop only ever covers index 0 - 31, so it should be within bounds.
I'm wondering if there is a Cuda specific consideration I'm not aware of (or just potentially a very dumb mistake I have overlooked)
Any help is appreciated

The amount of memory you can allocate on a GPU per kernel is very limited by default. 33 items seems small but your structure takes 16 bytes/items. This means 528 bytes/threads. Warp contains 32 threads so it means 16.5 KiB/warp. The thing is there are typically several warp executed in parallel per block and generally many blocks computed in parallel. With blocks of size 256 (8 warp/thread) and >100 blocks, the amount of required memory is >10 MiB. This is close to the default limit (AFAIK 8~16 MiB/kernel)... Alignement can make the amount of allocated memory possibly bigger.

You can increase this limit to something like 32-64 MiB so to check this. Note that using a to big amount of memory for that can also be a problem since multiple kernels can run in parallel en memory is AFAIK pre-reserved. Besides, new divider_node[32] should be fine here.

I see, I hadn't considered that this might have been a memory issue (I would have thought that Cuda would have reported out of memory instead of invalid global write). I tried with a smaller block size. I went from 32 x 16, down to 8 x 8 and I am still getting issues. I will try to increase the memory

You need to provide a minimal, reproducible example.

Ok. Note you can also use CUDA-GDB so to better track what is happening.

You should also check whether the div_nodes pointer is nullptr. device-side new does not throw an exception on allocation errors, it returns nullptr like malloc or new (nothrow)

Unfortunately due to IP protections at work I am not allowed to share more code that what I already have. I did not know that about the new not throwing, that's good to know for the future.
As for Cuda-GDB, I am currently on Windows. (I know there is NSight for Visual Studio but I am yet to get that working with CMake Cuda projects)

You're not supposed to share your whole company code. You're supposed to make a new, small code that exhibits the same behavior. This serves the double purpose of 1. giving us something to work with and 2. ensuring that the problem exists in the place that you suspect.

seems to be resolved, consistent with previous suggestions/comments here.

Try changing size_t to int in your loop. I have encountered the same error.
size_t is alias for long, which might be to big.

Afraid that didn't solve the issue.

First, long is far from enough to store values in the range [0;32]. In fact, it should be far from enough so store big values like 1_000_000_000 on all mainstream machines. Even 8-bit integers (the smallest ones) are enough to store them. Moreover, size_t is nearly always unsigned in C so it should be in CUDA. On 64-bit systems it is generally uint64_t. On 32-bit system, it is generally uint32_t. I have never seen any platform where is is long (even exotic ones, since at least 15 years). Thus, there is no reason to believe this is the problem.
